# What does adding a comma and a number mean in a Sybase SQL where expression?

Tags: sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

In managing a legacy codebase I've found a ",0.001" added to certain WHERE clause terms and I can't quite figure out why. I've abstracted this below:

[image]

It's quite hard to Google and I couldn't find anything in the Sybase documentation.

What does this do?

I thought it may be precision but I wasn't able to confirm that, and I thought it might be functioning like an IN but that doesn't seem to be the case:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a [selectivity estimate](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/estimates-condition.html). It has no semantic meaning, but influences the optimizer.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert! Write that up as an answer and I'll accept. :)